# Play 2.4 dependency injection forgets about builtin classes in unit tests if modules are added

Tags: java, unit-testing, playframework

We're migrating our Java-only Play application from Play 2.4 to Play 2.5. First step: Get rid of `GlobalSettings`, still completely in the 2.4 realm. I wrote some `StartModule` which will take over functionality as the migration guide and "the internet" describes. I add

```
play.modules.enabled += "de.[...].modules.StartModule"
```

to the application's `.conf` file. Executing this via `sbt run` or `sbt start` works as expected. Massive problems, however, arise when I try to unittest this stuff with `sbt test` or `sbt test-only`.

We have a rather elaborated unit test setup as the application is complex and has large legacy parts. Eventually, the unit test instance of the Play server is started with

```
Helpers.start(testserver=Helpers.testServer(playhttpport,
    app=new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
      .configure(getConfiguration())
      .build()));
```

This works as long as the `play.modules.enabled` line above is not visible to the unit test code. As soon as I enable it, I get a number of errors like

```
Test de.[...]Tests failed: com.google.inject.CreationException:
   Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for play.inject.ApplicationLifecycle was bound.
   while locating play.inject.ApplicationLifecycle
```

or

```
2) Could not find a suitable constructor in play.api.Environment.
   Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject
   or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
```

Same thing happens if I remove the `play.modules.enabled` line and change the server start to

```
Helpers.start(testserver=Helpers.testServer(playhttpport,
  app=new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
    .load(Guiceable.modules(new StartModule()))
    .configure(getConfiguration())
    .build()));
```

In my limited understanding, it seems that `GuiceApplicationBuilder` (or whatever) "forgets" about all builtin dependency injection configuration if *any* additional dependency definitions are given. Unfortunately, I have not found any applicable postings here or anywhere else which would lead me to a solution.

Questions:

1. Is my analysis correct?
2. How can I make my unit test code functional with the additional module in the DI framework?
3. Would it be helpful to directly continue in Play 2.5? I'd like to solve this problem before as that migration step will bring its own plethora of things to handle and I'd really to have a functional base for this - including an operational unit test framework...

Any insight and help greatly appreciated!
Kind regards,
Dirk

**Update** This is `StartModule`:

```
public class StartModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override protected void configure() {
    bind(InnerServerLauncher.class).asEagerSingleton();
  }
}
```

And this is the `InnerServerLauncher`:

```
@Singleton
public class InnerServerLauncher {
  @Inject
  public InnerServerLauncher(ApplicationLifecycle lifecycle,
                             Environment environment) {
    System.err.println("*** Server launcher called ***");
  }
}
```

I should add that the problem also arises if I put a totally different class into `play.modules.enabled` like

```
play.modules.enabled += "play.filters.cors.CORSModule"
```

Comment: What does the `StartModule` contain? This sounds quite suspicious (not necessarily explaining your issue, but in general). These modules should contain bindings only (that is, be declarative) rather than contain some functionality.

Comment: I have added the code in question into the description above. It's all testing stubs following the cookbook examples. The problem is also triggered by any other module written into `play.modules.enabled`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally got it. Problem is the `configuration()` method which I mentioned above but did not elaborate further. As I said, we have quite some legacy in our system. Therefore, we have a mechanism which constructs the configuration independently from Play's config files for the unit tests. `GuiceBuilder.configure()` (and btw. also the `fakeApplication()`-based methods) merges this with the Play-internal configuration *but only on the topmost layer*. For plain settings (strings, numbers etc.) that's ok, but for value lists it means that *the complete list is overwritten and replaced*.

`play.modules.enabled` is used by Play internally to gather the default modules which have to be registered with the dependency injection framework. Documentation states very clearly that your statements in `application.conf` must only add elements to `play.modules.enabled`, i.e.

```
play.modules.enabled += "package.Module"
```

Our "special way" of constructing the configuration environment for unit tests, however, *overwrote* Play's own `play.modules.enabled` as soon as any value in our own configuration was set. And that destroyed the complete dependency injection scheme of Play as none of its own base classes were accessible any more. Bummer!

I solved this by actually using a "real" configuration file which is just read normally by `GuiceApplicationBuilder` and which contains those `play.modules.enabled += ...` lines. As this config file is still artifically and temporarily generated for the unit test scenario, I pass its name to `GuiceApplicationBuilder` via `System.setProperty`:

```
System.setProperty("config.file",conffilename);
Helpers.start(testserver=Helpers.testServer(playhttpport,
  app=new GuiceApplicationBuilder().build()));
```

Now, the configuration is created correctly and *with* the internal default settings for `play.modules.enabled`. Now, I finally can start to actually move the code from `GlobalSettings` into that injected and eagerly loaded module. And it was just ten hours of hunting...